# Reference an object's parent ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, parent

I have an Opportunity model that has Links as a nested resource. I wrote a callback so that whenever I add a new link, the built-in "updated_at" attribute for my model opportunity is updated to equal Time.now. However, I'm not sure how to reference the Opportunity model. I want to do something like this:

This is what I would put in my Link model, which is a nested resource of my Opportunity model:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :opportunity

after_save :update_updated_at

def update_updated_at
  @opportunity.updated_at = Time.now #this line is where I am unsure of how to reference the link's Opportunity parent
end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links in ActiveRecord are always accessed through method names. There is no instance variable called `@opportunity`, so that's equivalent to calling `updated_at=` on `nil`.

What you probably want is:

```
def update_parent
  return unless (self.opportunity)

  self.opportunity.updated_at = Time.now
  self.opportunity.save
end
```

From an implementation perspective this is a little rude as the Link object is bossing around the Opportunity one. That's usually something a controller should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

If a Link object `@link` belongs_to an Opportunity object `@opp`, you can find `@opp` if you know `@link` via the ActiveRecord relation `opportunity.` See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html for more details.

Given a link record, find the parent opportunity record:
`@opp = @link.opportunity`

So you could write `self.opportunity.updated_at = Time.now`